# What is the correct way to link a table too two other tables when either tables could be the correct option

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, normalization

## Preface

I have three tables Customers, Individuals & Companies and a customer can be an individual or a company but not both. I want to find out the general opinion on the correct way to link these three tables.

## Details with example

The three tables are "customers", "companies" & "individuals" and the MySQL code to generate the basic tables is:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`customers`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`customers` (
  `CustomerID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`individuals`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`individuals` (
  `IndividualID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `First Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Last Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `DOB` DATE NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IndividualID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`companies`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`companies` (
  `CompanyID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(60) NULL ,
  `StartedDate` DATE NULL ,
  `Address` VARCHAR(500) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CompanyID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

This is the basic tables with no links between them. I have toyed with several methods of linking the tables but none of them felt right. The first method was to basiclly pub a "IndividualID" & "CompanyID" in the Customer Table and a boolean to say which one it was but this left it open to potentially have both filled in and no way to reinforce it with the DB directly it also it just didn't feel right that was like this:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`companies`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`companies` (
  `CompanyID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(60) NULL ,
  `StartedDate` DATE NULL ,
  `Address` VARCHAR(500) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CompanyID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`individuals`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`individuals` (
  `IndividualID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `First Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Last Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `DOB` DATE NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IndividualID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`customers`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`customers` (
  `CustomerID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `bIsCompany` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL ,
  `IndividualID` INT NULL ,
  `CompanyID` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerID`) ,
  INDEX `Customer_Company` (`CompanyID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `Customer_Individual` (`IndividualID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `Customer_Company`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CompanyID` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`companies` (`CompanyID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Customer_Individual`
    FOREIGN KEY (`IndividualID` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`individuals` (`IndividualID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

The other method was to add two tables between the customer and other two tables that linked them and that felt better but not perfect as again you COULD have a link in both. That looked like this:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`customers`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`customers` (
  `CustomerID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`individuals`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`individuals` (
  `IndividualID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `First Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Last Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `DOB` DATE NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IndividualID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`companies`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`companies` (
  `CompanyID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(60) NULL ,
  `StartedDate` DATE NULL ,
  `Address` VARCHAR(500) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CompanyID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`company_customer`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`company_customer` (
  `CustomerID` INT NOT NULL ,
  `CompanyID` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerID`, `CompanyID`) ,
  INDEX `CompanyCustomer_CompanyID` (`CompanyID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `CompanyCustomer_CustomerID` (`CustomerID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `CompanyCustomer_CompanyID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CompanyID` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`companies` (`CompanyID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `CompanyCustomer_CustomerID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerID` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`customers` (`CustomerID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`individual_customer`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`individual_customer` (
  `IndividualID` INT NOT NULL ,
  `CompanyID` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IndividualID`, `CompanyID`) ,
  INDEX `CompanyCustomer_CompanyID` (`IndividualID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `CompanyCustomer_CustomerID` (`IndividualID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `IndividualCustomer_CompanyID0`
    FOREIGN KEY (`IndividualID` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`individuals` (`IndividualID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `IndividualCustomer_CustomerID0`
    FOREIGN KEY (`IndividualID` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`customers` (`CustomerID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

As I mentioned that last option was the method that I preferred but it still didn't feel correct and could still lead to problems. SO:

## Questions:

- Is there any other options
- What is the general opinion on the options stated and have I missed any advantages/disadvantages to these options.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need the in-between tables "individual_customer" and "company_customer"? Are those really a m:n relationship, meaning can a customer be related to multiple companies or individuals (and vice versa a company to multiple customers)? Or ist it just 1:1?

If it's 1:1 you could drop the in-between tables and add a column CustomerID to the "individuals" and "companies" tables. That would solve your "can't move the common data to the customer table" problem. And add the CustomerID to the primary key or a new unique key to prevent duplicate entries in those tables.

The possibility that a customer ends up as both a company and an individual still remains, but  that's a problem you're not going to solve (easily) unless you modify the tables as suggested by p.marino and Damir. You can't enforce that requirement in mySQL with a simple primary or unique key in the database, as long as the data is stored in multiple tables. Only application logic or a stored function / procedure could do that.

Comment: That was the first solution I presented above so definitely a good options. ;) I suspect I will have to go with one of my original options. I guess the answer is there isn't a better way! :( I will mark this as the accepted answer as none of them 'Solve' the problem BUT this explains the solution I used (even if it was in my question :p) and it will give you some rep! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Personally I will go for something based on OO principles.

Customer: would be the superclass. And it will have all elements that are common to both companies and individuals. I.e. Id, Name (and possibly a main-address or an ID to a main-address table, and anything else that is common to any Customer) plus a "Type" field (e.g.: "IND","COM").

Individuals: This has a foreign key to Customer and all fields that are specific of the Individual, like Middle Name, DOB etc. The Foreign key is also Unique.

Companies: Same - foreign key to Customer and Company-specific fields. The Foreign key is also Unique.

It is theoretically possible to have both an Individual and a Company record pointing to the same Customer entry, but the Type field will help ensuring that you can always write queries where a Customer is considered only as an Individual or a Company, and never both.

Example:

```
    Select * from Individuals where exists 
    (select 'x" from Customers 
                where customer-id=individual-id and type="IND").
```

------------------UPDATE:

You can always create views for the two type of customers to mitigate your problems with the split:

```
Select Individuals.id, 
       Individuals.field1, 
       Individuals.field2, 
       Customer.FieldX, Customer.FieldY 
 from Individuals ind, Customers Cus 
 where ind.id=cus.id and cus.type="IND"
```

is a way to "reconstruct" an Individual Customer taking fields from both tables. This allows you to access it as a whole, at least when reading it.

I am not sure what the problem could be in splitting the fields on two distinct tables, actually.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that I use the companies and individuals in other places in the application so merging them like this isn't really an option. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Place all common fields into `Customer` table.
`Company` and `Person` tables have only columns specific to each one.
The `Customer.CustomerType` is the discriminator.

[image]

Take a look at some **[similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:196713%20subtype)** too.

Comment: So basically the same as the first of my two examples but with the two ID links pointing to the same column in the customers table?

Comment: @Zasurus; Yes, the `CustomerID` propagates to sub-type tables; it is the primary and the foreign key at the same time. The discriminator `{C,P}` determines which type a record is.

Comment: @Zasursu - This is basically what I described in my answer, but you said it didn't work in your scenario.

Comment: @DamirSudarevic: As p.marino said this is the same as his answer (but less detailed :P) so the same problem applies. I can't move all of the common records into the customer record as they need to be separate else were. :(

Comment: No prob - Damir's answer has a nice diagram so it's probably more understandable than mine. I just wanted to point out that we were saying the same thing.